# How to extract lines containing blank in a specific column with Linux command

Tags: linux, command, extract, blank-line

**Example:**

```
aa\tab\tac\tad\tae
ba\tbb\tbc
ca\tcb\tcc
da\tdb\tdc\tdd
```

**Expected output:**

```
ba\tbb\tbc
ca\tcb\tcc
```

I want to extract lines containing blank in a 4th column with linux command. If you know the command, could you let me know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F"\\" '{if($4=="") print}' input_file
ba\tbb\tbc
ca\tcb\tcc
```

Comment: awk -F"\\t" '{if($4=="") print}' input_file

Comment: Same thing a bit shorter ;)  `awk -F'\' '$4==""' input_file` .. no need for an `if`, you can put the condition outside the `{}` ... and since `print` is awk's default action you can give the statement and the curlys a miss.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cut and use "" as delimiter and check the field 4 if it is not empty. Then use the grep -v to check if a trailing "" exists or not.
in an If statement you can get the result.

```
text='aa\tab\tac\'    

if [[ -z $(echo $text | cut -d \\ -f 4 | grep -v \\\\\$) ]]; then
    if[[ -z $(echo $text | grep -v \\\\\$) ]]; then
        echo $text
    else
        echo 'Text has a slash at the end'
    fi
else 
    echo 'Not valid input'
fi
```